# Spivak's Calculus Exercise 2-9

Tags: proof-verification, logic, induction, first-order-logic

This is exercise 2-9 from Spivak's Calculus:

> Prove that if a set $A$ of natural numbers contains $n_0$ and contains $k + 1$ whenever it contains $k$, then $A$ contains all natural numbers $> n_0$.

Spivak's solution goes something like this: Let $B = \{l \in \mathbb{N} \mid n_0 + l \in A \}$. Clearly $0 \in B$. Now suppose $l \in B$. This means $n_0 + l \in A$. By the property of $A$ it follows that $n_0 + l + 1 \in A$ and thus $l+1 \in B$. Therefore, $B = \mathbb{N}$ and $A$ contains all $n \ge n_0$.

My attempted solution, however, was more mechanical. I will readily admit that defining $B$ to be an inductive set in terms of $A$ is way more elegant, but I still wanted to run my proof by math.se to see if it has any flaws in its logical construction. This is my proof:

Let $P(n) := n\ge n_0 \to n\in A$. For the inductive hypothesis, suppose $P(n)$ is true, and suppose $n+1 \ge n_0$. If $n+1 = n_0$ then clearly $n+1 \in A$. If $n+1 > n_0$, then $n \ge n_0$, so by assumption $n \in A$. By the property of $A$ it also follows that $n+1\in A$. Hence $P(n+1)$ is also true. For the base case, if $n_0 > 0$, then $P(0)$ is vacuously true. If $n_0 = 0$, then $0 \in A$ and $P(0)$ is true as well. Therefore, $\forall n \ge n_0(n\in A)$.

The interesting question is if this base case proof works correctly.

Comment: If $P(n)$ is true, then $n \geq n_{0}$ and it immediately follows that $n+1 > n_{0}$.  So you do not need to suppose $n+1 \geq n_{0}$ and the $n+1 = n_{0}$ is unnecessary.

Comment: I disagree. Assuming $P(n)$ tells you nothing about the precise value of $n$. It tells that if it is greater than $n_0$, then it is in $A$, but you don't know that it is greater than $n_0$.

Comment: True, but if $n \geq n_{0}$ then it must be true that $n+1 > n_{0}$

Comment: If $n+1 = n_{0}$, then $n = n_{0} - 1$ and so $n < n_{0}$, but this can't happen under your assumption that $P(n)$ is true

Comment: But you don't know $n \ge n_0$, you are given $n + 1 \ge n_0$. After all, it may very well be the case that $n + 1 = n_0$, in which case $n < n_0$ so you can't use the assumption of $P(n)$ at all.

Comment: "and so $n<n0$, but this can't happen under your assumption that $P(n)$ is true"
It 100% can happen. The assumption $P(n)$ tells you that **IF** $n \ge n_0$ then $n \in A$. But you don't know that much. Conditional statements are generally not strong.

Comment: @MuchToLearn: your proof is correct.